# How do I know what prior's I'm giving to sci-kit learn? (Naive-bayes classifiers.)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In sci-kit learn's naive bayesian classifiers you can specify the prior probabilities, and the classifier will use those provided probabilities in it's calculations.  But I don't know how the prior probabilities should be ordered.

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
data = [[0], [1]]
classes = ['light bulb', 'door mat']
classes.shuffle()  # This simulates getting classes from a complex source.
classifier = BernoulliNB(class_prior=[0, 1])  # Here we provide prior probabilities.
classifier.fit(data, classes)
```

In the above code, how do I know which class is assumed to be the 100% prior?  Do I need to consider the order of the classes in the data before specifying prior probabilities?

I would also be interested in knowing where this documented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be undocumented. When fit, target is preprocessed by `LabelBinarizer`, so you can get your data's classes with

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
labelbin = LabelBinarizer()
labelbin.fit_transform(classes)
```

Then `labelbin.classes_` contains resulting classes for your target data (`classes`), in order corresponding to one of priors.

Comment: It's not documented for Naive Bayes, but it's a convention throughout scikit-learn that per-class parameters work like this. A patch is welcome.

Comment: So I do have to do a little extra work to get the class_prior order correct. It would be nice if class_prior would accept a dictionary. Maybe I will look into a patch as larsmans mentions.

Answer (score 2):

The order is that of `classes` after sorting, so P(`light bulb`)=.4 would be specified using `[.6, .4]` because `"door mat" < "light bulb"`.

Comment: Does this conflict with alko's answer? Or does LabelBinarizer order the classes the way you've described?

Comment: @Buttons840: this is exactly the order that alko's answer produces.

Answer (score 1):

Deeply nested within the code base the following happens: The classes you provide samplewise to the call of `fit()` are turned into a set, sorted and then stored in that order in the classifier object (alphabetical or numerical order). The priors provided for `__init__()` correspond to the classes in this exact order.

Apparantly this is undocumented.

For further reading:

- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/naive_bayes.py
- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py
- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py